# How to use the keyboard shortcut in anki to enter a LaTeX equation?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, latex, anki

Anki's dialog for entering cards has a shortcut to enter a LaTeX equation.  In the menu (far right of the menu bar) it's labelled `Ctrl T, E`.

What does that mean?  What keys do I have to press in what order to enter an equation?  As far as I can tell, neither `Ctrl-T`, nor `Ctrl-T` followed by `Ctrl-E`, nor `Ctrl-T` followed by plain `E`, have any effect.

Of course I realise I can just type in the `[$]` and `[/$]` -- but if there's a way that's faster to type using a keyboard shortcut I'd like to use that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that the shortcut works is the following:

- Type the LaTeX expression in the field
- Mark the expression with the mouse (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> if it's just the expression in the field)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> followed by just <kbd>E</kbd>, which will wrap it into `[$]` and `[/$]`

Comment: I "knew" that I'd tried this already.  Of course, I hadn't :-/  Thank you!